# How to use malloc in a c function?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, free

I want to make a C function for FIR filter, It has a two input arrays and one output array. 
both input arrays are constant numbers, I want to use them for computation of output of filter,and after computation delete them and just store the output array of function this is my code but it does not work

```
#include <stdlib.h>
float   * filter(float *PATIENTSIGNAL,float *FILTERCOEF, int lengthofpatient , int lengthoffilter ){
    static float FIROUT[8000];
    int i,j;
    float temp=0;
    float* SIGNAL;
    float* COEF;
    SIGNAL = malloc(lengthofpatient *sizeof(float));
    COEF = malloc(lengthoffilter*sizeof(float));
    }
    for (j = 0; j <= lengthofpatient; j++){
        temp = SIGNAL[j] * COEF[0];
        for (i = 1; i <= lengthoffilter; i++){
            if ((j - i) >= 0){
                temp += SIGNAL[j - i] * COEF[i];
            }
            FIROUT[j] = temp;
        }
    }
    free(SIGNAL);
    free(COEF);
    free(PATIENTSIGNAL);
    return FIROUT;
}
```

Comment: SIGNAL and COEF are allocated but not initialised when you use temp variable.

Comment: `for (j = 0; j <= lengthofpatient; j++)` This will loop once more than required. The same for the `i` loop.

Comment: Shouldn't you remove the `}` right after `COEF = malloc(lengthoffilter*sizeof(float));` since it seems to terminate your function declaration?

Comment: What is the purpose of `float *PATIENTSIGNAL,float *FILTERCOEF` in the function parameter?

Comment: Formatting the code properly would be a big help.

Comment: Probably not a good idea to use signal as an identifer

Comment: Rather than `SIGNAL = malloc(lengthofpatient *sizeof(float));`, consider `SIGNAL = malloc(lengthofpatient * sizeof *SIGNAL);`.  Easier to code, read and maintain.  Less likely to be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in your code,

1. Unnecessary `}` after line `COEF = malloc(lengthoffilter*sizeof(float));`.
2. `for (j = 0; j <= lengthofpatient; j++)`. This will loop once more than required. The same for the i loop. **pmg** mentioned it in the comment.
3. `temp += SIGNAL[j - i] * COEF[i];` will not give you the desired outcome, as you do not initialized both `SIGNAL` or `COEF`.
4. Whats the purpose of `float *PATIENTSIGNAL,float *FILTERCOEF` in the function parameter?

From a *wild* guess, I think you need this two line to initialize `SIGNAL` and/or `COEF`.

```
memccpy(SIGNAL, PATIENTSIGNAL, lengthofpatient);
memccpy(COEF, FILTERCOEF, lengthoffilter);
```

Don't `free` `PATIENTSIGNAL` in your local function. Let this be done by the function caller.